# Using XPath to select nodes outside of the normal sequence of xsl:for-each

Tags: html, xml, xslt, ektron

I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Collection>
    <Content>
        <ID>12</ID>
        <Type>Content</Type>
        <Title>Office Location #1</Title>
        <QuickLink>/office.aspx?id=12</QuickLink>
        <Teaser>
            <p>
                <span class="infoBold">My Group</span>
                <br />
                WPO
                <br />
                Office Location #1
                <br />
                Wp, NY 090801
                <br />
                986.362.3265
            </p>
        </Teaser>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <Location>
                    <location />
                    <office>WPO</office>
                    <Address>
                        <image>
                            <img src="someing.png" />
                        </image>
                        <Address1>Office Location #1</Address1>
                        <Address2 />
                        <City>Wp</City>
                        <State>NY</State>
                        <zip>09081</zip>
                        <phone>986.362.3265</phone>
                        <fax />
                        <urgent_care_phone />
                    </Address>
                </Location>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <ID>48</ID>
        <Type>Content</Type>
        <Title>Office Location #3</Title>
        <QuickLink>/office.aspx?id=48</QuickLink>
        <Teaser>
            <p>
                <span class="infoBold">My Group</span>
                <br />
                WPO
                <br />
                Office Location #3
                <br />
                Wp, NY 090801
                <br />
                986.362.3265
            </p>
        </Teaser>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <Location>
                    <location />
                    <office>WPO</office>
                    <Address>
                        <image>
                            <img src="someing.png" />
                        </image>
                        <Address1>Office Location #3</Address1>
                        <Address2 />
                        <City>Wp</City>
                        <State>NY</State>
                        <zip>09081</zip>
                        <phone>986.362.3265</phone>
                        <fax />
                        <urgent_care_phone />
                    </Address>
                </Location>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <ID>36</ID>
        <Type>Content</Type>
        <Title>Office Location #2</Title>
        <QuickLink>/office.aspx?id=36</QuickLink>
        <Teaser>
            <p>
                <span class="infoBold">My Group</span>
                <br />
                WPO
                <br />
                Office Location #2
                <br />
                Wp, NY 090801
                <br />
                986.362.3265
            </p>
        </Teaser>
        <Html>
            <root>
                <Location>
                    <location>WP</location>
                    <office>WPO</office>
                    <Address>
                        <image>
                            <img src="someing.png" />
                        </image>
                        <Address1>Office Location #2</Address1>
                        <Address2 />
                        <City>Wp</City>
                        <State>NY</State>
                        <zip>09081</zip>
                        <phone>986.362.3265</phone>
                        <fax />
                        <urgent_care_phone />
                    </Address>
                </Location>
            </root>
        </Html>
    </Content>
</Collection>
```

I want to display the following format:

```
FOR EACH ENTRY inside `Collection/Content/`:

    Html/root/Location/location (if not blank show it)
    Html/root/Location/Address {
        /Address1
        /Address2 (if not blank show it)
        /City
        /State
        /zip
        /phone
        /fax (if not blank show it)
    }

    Html/root/Location/location (if not blank show it)
    Html/root/Location/Address {
        /Address1
        /Address2 (if not blank show it)
        /City
        /State
        /zip
        /phone
        /fax (if not blank show it)
    }

    Html/root/Location/location (if not blank show it)
    Html/root/Location/Address {
        /Address1
        /Address2 (if not blank show it)
        /City
        /State
        /zip
        /phone
        /fax (if not blank show it)
    }
```

I am trying to get the `QuickLink`

```
<xsl:for-each select="Collection/Content/Html">
    <div class="serviceHolder brClear">
        <xsl:value-of select="root/Location/Address/Address1" />
        <xsl:value-of select="root/Location/Address/Address2" />
        <xsl:value-of select="root/Location/Address/City" />
        <xsl:value-of select="root/Location/Address/State" />
        <xsl:value-of select="root/Location/Address/zip" />
        <xsl:value-of select="root/Location/Address/phone" />
        <a href="{QuickLink}" title="Test">Get Direction</a>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Although I am using the `Collection/Content/Html` in the for-each, how do I go back to `Collection/Content/QuickLink` for the anchor link here:

```
<a href="{QuickLink}" title="Test">Get Direction</a>
```

Comment: If you want to get useful responses, make sure all of your code shows up and your expected output is *prececisely* what you want. (i.e., if you want HTML, write HTML, not some vague mish-mash of curly braces, parentheses and slashes.)

Comment: Also, please choose your title properly.  This is not about "How to use XSLT to display XML to the browser"; it's about routine XPath selection related to code in/near a `xsl:for-each` construct.  Edited to *Using XPath to select nodes outside of the normal sequence of xsl:for-each*.

Comment: Thanks. I think it makes more sense now. So any idea how to get the `QuickLink`

Comment: @Tomalak I did provide an example of what I am looking to do and what I am requesting assistance with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `a` generation problem, make the XPath to `QuickLink` relative to the context node within the `xsl:for-each` by changing:

```
<a href="{QuickLink}" title="Test">Get Direction</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{../QuickLink}" title="Test">Get Direction</a>
```

As for generating the rest of your pseudo markup in HTML by writing XSLT for you, I'd prefer to help with specific question rather than crank out code for you.  Let us know if you have any other specific questions.